# How to make div (inside another div) horizontally and vertically align

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have 3 divs which are horizontally aligned (aqua color). Inside each div, there are two divs (red and black one).

What I am trying to do is, align the black divs horizontally regardless of the red div. The css for the black div is

```css
.black-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  max-width: 235px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #33244a;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 43px;
  border: 2px dashed #d5d1d8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Output will something like this
[image]

I am not good at all in css. I have tried using position: fixed / absolute but no luck.

Comment: Wrap your `textarea` element in a `div` and set `min-height` equal to the height of largest element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

Use `div` and `min-height`.

```css
section{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
.textarea-wrap{
  overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.textarea-wrap > textarea{
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;

}
.red{
  background-color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <div class="textarea-wrap">
      <textarea rows="3">12312312</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
      red
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <div class="textarea-wrap">
      <textarea rows="10">12312312</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
      red
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <div class="textarea-wrap">
      <textarea rows="6">12312312</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
      red
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this wont work if the content exceeds the min-height.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table to make it more manageable, or use absolute positioning on the black div so you can position them measure from the bottom of the blue div.

Comment: Its not a bad idea to keep it simple. You can use tables to get the desired effect - why not? +1

Answer (score 0):

There may be a solution without the spacer. Im looking for it :)

**found solution without spacer** `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* flex in a row inside (make columns .col) */
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* flex in a column inside */
  justify-content: space-between; /* since the elements must not grow, fill the space between them */
  
  flex: 1 1 100px; /* grow and shrink of col allowed to fill row evenly starting at 100px*/
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.red {
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* no vertical (col) growing (so it does not expand vertically) */
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* no growing allowed */
}

.resize {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='red'>Some wide wide wide wide wide wide Text</div>
    <div class='black'>Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='red'>Some<br/>much<br/>longer<br/>Text</div>
    <div class='black'>Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='red resize'>Some Text<br><b><u>Resize me!</u></b></div>
    <div class='black'>Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** removed spacer div

**Edit2** added css commenting for easier understanding